Identifying a story within a black widower's story by Asimov
In More Tales of the Black Widowers, "Earthset and Evening Star", Dr. Drake says the following lines

“I just read a mystery,” said James Drake in his softly hoarse smoker's voice, “in which the whole point rested on character 1 being really character 2, because the real character 1 was dead. I was put on to it at once because, in the list of characters at the start, character 1 was not listed. Ruined the story for me.”

Does anyone know which story he might be referring to. Did Asimov himself say anything anywhere?

No, Asimov did not comment on that. In addition to the afterword in More Tales of the Black Widowers, he also talked about the story in Opus 200 and in In Joy Still Felt, but he did not address this issue.

Thank you. I have not been able to read Opus 200.

I think it is entirely fictional.
It's part of a longer conversation about  inadvertent spoilers in general.  I think it is worthwhile giving an extended quote

“Exactly,” said Rubin. “For instance, what I've been writing is essentially a short story if one moves in a straight line. The trouble is the line is so straight, the reader will see its end before I'm halfway. So I have to hide one crucial piece of evidence, and do it in such a way that I don't make an idiot plot out of it. So I invent a reason to hide that piece, and in order to make the reason plausible I have to build a supporting structure around it—and I end with a novel, and a damn good one.” His sparse beard quivered with self-satisfaction.
Henry, the perennial waiter at the Black Widowers' banquets, removed the plate from in front of Rubin with his usual dexterity. Rubin, without turning, said, “Am I right, Henry?”
Henry said softly, “As a mystery reader, Mr. Rubin, I find it more satisfying to have the piece of information delivered to me and to find that I have been insufficiently clever and did not notice.”
“I just read a mystery,” said James Drake in his softly hoarse smoker's voice, “in which the whole point rested on character 1 being really character 2, because the real character 1 was dead. I was put on to it at once because, in the list of characters at the start, character 1 was not listed. Ruined the story for me.”
“Yes,” said Rubin, “but that wasn't the author's fault Some flunky did that. I once wrote a story which was accompanied by one illustration that no one thought to show me in advance. It happened to give away the point.”

Rubin's story is certainly fictional, there's no reason to think Drake's story is real.
I have always suspected that it is Asimov's reaction to a blurb on the cover that contains a major spoiler for one of his stories.  I have no direct proof,  but the timing fits so closely. Also, the spoilerd story matches Henry's comment about information given to the astute reader.
This particular edition of The Martian Way and Other Stories was printed 1974. The Black Widowers story was published in 1975.


93.5 pence for a book? Certainly an interesting price

That back cover blurb contains major spoilers for at least TWO stories.

Interesting. The Spoiler for youth is horrible. The Blurb writer must have been entirely thick headed. But the reason I think It could be christie (A murder is announced) is Asimov is a die hard christie fan. He refers to in passing ' Murder of Roger Ackroyd' when there is talk about the narrators (In a different black widowers story). There is talk of Arsene lupin and other detectives novels- I think something by Le Carr. So I thought this might also refer to a real one.
